# subfigure in Strip environment

Tags: graphics, subfloats, cuted

I use `strip` environment from `cuted` package to put a wide image in a two column text format just like Fig. 12 this:

[image]

Now there are two problems:

1. I can't put the image at the top of page unless I manually move the code to where the earliest text of where this page begins, i.e., there is nothing like `[!ht]` or so. Is there?
2. I have a figure which contains two subfigures and I want it to cover two columns again. How can I define something like `subfigure` in the `strip` environment? I have the below image and I use this code. This figure is thrown away to after the references which is incongruous.

[image]

```
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
 \centering
\subfigure[]{%\label{fig:ch4cyclic}
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{Scenario1-path.pdf}\label{fig:sc1desvsact}}
 ~
\subfigure[]{%\label{fig:ch4cyclic}
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth,trim=300 0 0 0,clip]{Scenario1-err.pdf}\label{fig:sc1err}}
 \caption{Comparison between desired and actual performance (a) and observed errors (b) in the first scenario}
 \label{fig:sc1}
 \end{figure*}
```

Here is a link to the minimal code:
[Minimal Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4HvZ54rtS9kMmFiUGdjTG4tTU0)

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something, but doesn't the `figure*` environment alone do what you want?

Comment: The `strip` environment is not a floating environment. On the other hand, `figure*`is, and places its contents at the top of page.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.~
The problem is indeed with being float. It throws the figures to the end of document (after references) which is not acceptable. If there is a way to use float in such a way it respects the recalling place, it would be the solution.

Comment: I think usually `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` would place the figure on the top of the next page. This might depend on documentclass, figure size and other things though, so I think it would be hard for anyone to say more without more information about your document. A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) might be useful.

Comment: The minimal code is attached. You can see and try it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment I think (you didn't ping me). Anyways, it's *much* better if you can include the MWE directly in your question, instead of linking to external files.